# Getting count of nested relationship with 'withCount' method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm in need of help of figuring out how to get withCount() to work with nested relationships.

I have so far tried this

```
return CharityArea::with('campaigns.sponsor', 'campaigns.charityArea', 'campaigns.charityDetail')->withCount('campaigns.users')->where($matchTheseThings)->get();
```

Basically, I want to get the count of the users in the campaigns model.

The relationship on the CampaignsModel looks like this:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserPreferences', 'campaign_id', 'id');
}
```

The relationship to campaigns in CharityArea looks like this

```
public function campaigns(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Campaigns', 'charity_area_id', 'id');
}
```

Laravel throws and error saying that 'campaigns.users' is not found.

Any ideas on how else to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share as well the `campaigns()` relationship in your `CharityAreaModel` ?

Comment: Sure, I have updated the post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use first set a ManyThrough relation in your `CharityArea` model.

```
    function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\UserPreferences', 'App\Campaigns');
    }
```

Then you can call `withCount()` on it:

```
    return CharityArea::with('campaigns.sponsor', 'campaigns.charityArea', 'campaigns.charityDetail')
        ->withCount('users')
        ->where($matchTheseThings)
        ->get();
```